# Overfitted model performs better in test set

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, overfitting

There are two models for the same task:

**model_1:** 98% accuracy on training set, 54% accuracy on test set.
**model_2:** 48% accuracy on training set, 47% accuracy on test set.

From the statistics above we can say that **model_1** overfits training set.
**Q1:** Can we say that **model_2** underfits?
**Q2:** Why **model_1** is bad choice if it performs better than **model_2** on test set?